# How to shorten multiple timeseries with different dates?

Tags: r, date, merge, xts

I am using timeseries data which were obtained from different providers. This leads to the fact that the length of the vectors are not matching.

e.g.:

```
nrow(xts_ret)       #2176
nrow(xts_trade)     #2177
nrow(xts_trans)     #2192
nrow(xts_vola_ret)  #2177
```

I have one additional timeseries which contains solely factors:

```
> head(xts_sentiment)

           [,1]      
2019-04-29 "neutral" 
2019-04-29 "negative"
2019-04-29 "neutral" 
2019-04-29 "neutral" 
2019-04-29 "neutral" 
2019-04-29 "neutral"
```

Note: all above vectors are formated as "xts"-objects.

The main problem of this setting is that the dates of the xts_ret, xts_trade, xts_trans, xts_vola_ret and xts_sentiment differs by variable.

I am using R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02).

I found the "merge" command for xts which does exactly what I want

```
data_pool <- merge(xts_ret, xts_trade, xts_trans, xts_vola_ret)
```

If one date (or value) is missing, it replaces its entry in the respective vector with "NA" but lists this entry in the line with the respective date.

```
> head(data_pool)

               xts_ret xts_trade xts_trans xts_vola_ret
2013-04-28          NA        NA     40986           NA
2013-04-29  0.04805079         0     50009   0.00000000
2013-04-30 -0.04805079         0     48795  -0.04516775
2013-05-01 -0.14532060         0     50437  -0.13931143
2013-05-02 -0.12327888         0     57278  -0.12424083
2013-05-03 -0.12792566         0     55859  -0.12770457
```

The "complete.case"-function allows me to kick out all lines, which have a "NA" entry so that all vectors have the same length.

Problem:

if I add the xts_sentiment vector to my pool variable, it contains solely "NA" values and the "complete.cases" removes every line of the dataset.

If I take a look at the xts_sentiment variable it self (see above) it contains the correct values.

I also tried to set "as.character(xts_sentiment)" or "as.string(xts_sentiment)" in the "merge"-command but it did not help.

Has anyone an idea how to get the values of the xts_sentiment into the "pool"-variable?

BTW: I also tried data.table, which displays xts_sentiment with all of its value but I have not the benefit of the "unique" dates.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

The soltuion of my problem was:

The variable xts_sentiment consists of characters.

XTS functions work as matrices, that means every vector needs the same content (e.g. all vectors contain solely characters or all vectors solely contain numbers).

So, it is not possible to create a xts element out of a character vector and a vector with numbers.

My solution was to decode the sentiment levels into numbers and use the "merge.xts" command. That worked.